# flutter build or hot reload not working in vs code

Tags: flutter, dart

this is the error:

> Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
> lib\main.dart:1 Exception: Unable to find suitable Visual Studio
> toolchain. Please run `flutter doctor` for more details. Exited
> (sigterm)

when i run flutter doctor it show me this

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows 
    [Version 10.0.22483.1011], locale en-IN) 
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted. To resolve this, run:     
    flutter doctor --android-licenses     
[√] Chrome - develop for the web 
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows X Visual Studio not installed;
    this is necessary for Windows development.
    Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. 
    Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, 
    including all of its default components 
[√] Android Studio (version 4.2) 
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3) 
[√] VS Code (version 1.61.2) 
[√] Connected device (4 available)
```

vs code is completely fine with flutter according to flutter doctor
please anybody help with this.

Comment: run "flutter doctor --android-licenses" and accept all licenses.

Answer (score 1):

run the following command in terminal

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

and pass y for yes when asked

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you saved the files that have changed prior to clicking the Hot Reload button. Modified files are not automatically saved when clicking this button.